# CKEDITOR textarea value is sent null to controller action in Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, ckeditor4.x

I'm using CKEditor 4 and I'm going to post ckeditor value to Edit Action.
but when I click on submit button , ckeditor value is sent Null to the
controller edit action. I used getData() for get ckeditor value but it
didn't work.

This is Edit View:

```
@model DataLayer.Models.ViewModels.Post.ShowPostListItemViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Post Edit";
}

<div class="row">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="hidden" asp-for="PostId" />
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Edit Post</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-8">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    
                    <div class="panel-body col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                       
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Title"></span>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <label>Category</label>
                            <select type="text" asp-for="GroupId" asp-items="@(ViewData["Groups"] as SelectList)" class="form-control"></select>
                        </div>
                      
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                      
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <label>PostDescription</label>
                            <textarea id="Post_PostDescription"  class="form-control" asp-for="Description" rows="10"></textarea>
                            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Description"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default ">
                
                   
                    <div class="panel-body col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                       <span class="border"></span>
                  
                        @await Component.InvokeAsync("EditPostImageComponent",Model)
                  
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                       <p></p>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Select Image</label>
                                <input type="file" name="imgPostUp" id="imgPostUp"  multiple="multiple">
                            </div>
       
                        </div>
                     </div>
      
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-11">
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="EditPost" value="Edit" class="btn btn-success" />
                    <a href="~/Admin/Post/GetPost" class="btn btn-danger ">Back</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        
        function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#imgPost').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        $("#imgPostUp").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
        });
    </script>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.9.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>
      
   
        CKEDITOR.replace('Post_PostDescription', {
            customConfig: '/js/Config.js'
        });
   
    </script>
}
```

This is Edit action method in Controller:

```
     [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult EditPost(ShowPostListItemViewModel showPostListItemViewModel, IFormFile[] imgPostUp)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View("EditPost");

            _postService.UpdatePost(showPostListItemViewModel, imgPostUp);
            return RedirectToAction("GetPost","Post");
        }
```

This is ShowPostListItemViewModel:

```
 public class ShowPostListItemViewModel  
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public int PostImageId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string? GroupTitle { get; set; }
        public string? ImageName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

    }
```

How can I post ckeditor  value to controller action to edit?
thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

> ckeditor value is sent Null to the controller edit action

I test your code, and  I can get the value, but even I don't have `/js/Config.js`, try to commentary `Config.js`, and try. Or check  your Config.js to find the reason.

result:

[image]

**Update**

Below is a work demo(.Net 6) based on your code, you can refer to the follow steps to creat a new project or check your project.

1. ShowPostListItemViewModel is yours.

2.PostController:

```
   [Area("Admin")]
    public class PostController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult EditPost()
        {
            //do your staff...
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult EditPost(ShowPostListItemViewModel showPostListItemViewModel, IFormFile[] imgPostUp)
        {    
            //do your staff...    
            return View();
        }
    }
```

3.EditPost view:

I don't have the Component so I   commentary `@await Component.InvokeAsync("EditPostImageComponent",Model)`
Then I change like yours:

```
 <script> CKEDITOR.replace('Description'); </script>
```

4.In Program.cs add below route, you can read [Areas in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know more:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Admin",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

5.Copy the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file and  `_ViewStart.cshtml` file to the appropriate view folder under areas.

6. The structure is like below:

[image]

Comment: I  removed /js/Config.js and changed it to:<script>
      CKEDITOR.replace('Description');
    </script> and It doesn't work yet.